# The intersection of the facets on the polyhedron

Tags: convex-geometry, affine-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes

Given a point set $E=\{\alpha_j\}_{j=1}^m\subset \mathbb{N}^{n}$ ($1\leq m< \infty$).

Define the polyhedron $\mathcal{N}(E)$ to be the convex hull of the set
\begin{equation*}
    \bigcup_{j=1}^m \left(\alpha_j + \mathbb{R}^n_{+}\right),
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbb{R}^n_+=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:x_j\geq 0, \, 1 \leq j\leq n\}$. If there are $n$ facet (the face has dimension $n-1$)
$
F_1,\,F_2,\,\cdots,\,F_n
$
on $\mathcal{N}(E)$ satisfying
$$
\bigcap_{j=1}^n F_j\neq \emptyset.
$$

How to prove that for $n\geq 3$, if the intersection of $n$ facets is nonempty, then it must be a single point?

For a general convex polytopes, this claim is not feasible. For a 4-dimensional example, see [Show that each edge of the cyclic polytope $C_4(6)$ is contained in either three or four facets, and either three or four 2-faces.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3132624/show-that-each-edge-of-the-cyclic-polytope-c-46-is-contained-in-either-three)

I think the concepts of redundant face maybe helpful. And I can only prove the case $n=3$, in the following answer (I post it to avoid a length question) I show if three facets intersect, then they must coincide with a single point.

Comment: Is it true that $\mathcal{N}(E) = \mathbb{R}^n_{+} + \Gamma(E)$ where $\Gamma(E)$ is convex hull of $E?$

Comment: yeah and we can assume that $E$ is finite.

Comment: Then, I guess, you can find all facets of $\mathcal{N}(E)$ from facets of  $\Gamma(E)$ and $\mathbb{R}^n_{+} $ and maybe apply counterexample you provided.

Comment: It is different.  That counterexample is a bounded closed polytope.

Comment: Thanks, I thought facets $\mathcal{N}(E)$ is union of some subset of facets of $\Gamma(E)$ (which is also bounded polytope) and of some subset of facets of $\mathbb{R}^n_{+}.$

Comment: The union of facets on $\mathcal{N}(E)$ is not a convex polyhedra.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I meant that each facet of $\mathcal{N}(E)$ is either facet of $\Gamma(E)$ or facet of $\mathbb{R}^n_{+}.$

Comment: what do you mean by "each $\mathcal{N}(E)$"?

Comment: "Each facet of $\mathcal{N}(E)$"

Answer (score 1):

This answer is only for the case $n=3$.

Since the affine hull of a facet is a 2-dimensional plane, there exist $w_j\in \mathbb{R}^n$ ($n=3$) such that the equation of these (support) plane is $w_{j}\cdot x=1$, $j=1,2,3$, with $$\mathcal{N}(E)\subset\bigcap_{j=1}^3\{x:w_j\cdot x\geq 1\}.$$ In our framework, one can easily show that $w_j\in \mathbb{R}^{n}_+$ (in higher dimension this fact is also true). Then our claim is equivalent to the linear independence of $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$. If they are not linear independent, we show there is a contradiction. Firstly, we can assume that there exist $\lambda_j$, $j=1,2$ such that
$$
w_3=\lambda_1 w_1+\lambda_2 w_2.
$$
Let $\beta\in \cap_{j=1}^3 F_j$ is a point on $\mathcal{N}(E)$. Then $\beta\cdot w_j=1$. Thus $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$. Without loss of generality, we can always assume that $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are non-negative. (Indeed, if there is a negative, say $\lambda_1$, then  we rewrite the relation of $w_j$ as
$$
w_2=\frac{1}{\lambda_2}(w_3-\lambda_1 w_1)=:\mu_1 w_3+\mu_2 w_1
$$

with $\mu_j$ non-negative.)

Now we assume $\lambda_j$ are non-negative, however, since $w_3$ is the normal vector of the (proper) facet $F_3$, we can choose $\alpha\in F_3$ and $\alpha$ not belong to $F_1,F_2$, then $w_j\cdot\alpha>1$ for $j=1,2$. And
$$
1=w_3\cdot\alpha=\lambda_1 w_1\cdot \alpha+\lambda_2 w_2\cdot \alpha>\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1.
$$
A contradiction.

In higher dimensions, I can also use a similar arguments but I stuck.